# Liferay JMX beans

Tags: liferay, monitoring, jmx

I need to plan monitoring of Liferay 6.1 running on Glassfish 3.1.2. So far we determined Glassfish  mbans we want to monitor.

The question is:

- does Liferay provide any MBeans in addittion to those provided by app server (liferay specific mbans) ?
- if so, are there any *industry standard* liferay mbeans that are worth to monitor in general ?

References to existing Liferay docs are welcome (actually may suffice for the whole answer). So far I could not find anything in official docs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you'll find "industry standard" mbeans, as Liferay is a platform that is used in many completely different ways: E.g. you might want to monitor the MessageBoards caches if you have a forum-like installation that suffers performance in that area. If you don't have enough content of a specific type, it doesn't make sense to monitor that cache.

That being said, from the top of my head I remember that the caches are available for your monitoring.

My recommendation is to browse through the MBeans and figure out if the given values make sense for your installation and usecase. They do have quite descriptive names.

Also, keep in mind that in general production you'll monitor other values than e.g. during performance tuning. (Coming back to caches: It makes sense to dimension the caches according to their actual size - but they wouldn't vary greatly day to day. So looking at them manually - when you want to change some config - makes sense

Comment: As for the part about browsing existing MBeans:
Is there any Liferay mbeans listing available ? Or how could I determine what mbeans are available ?

Comment: connect jconsole and browse?